# How do I get mailsettings form webconfig file on a classic asp page

Tags: .net, webforms, asp-classic

Currently working on a classic asp page and wanted to find out how would one go about sending an email when an event occurs on the page. using server-side coding, ie no javascript; how would I read the mailsetting within the web.config file on a classic asp page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having classic ASP read in a key from appsettings in a web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28960446)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0` object to load and read the `web.config` file and extract elements.

**Example web.config:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="smtp@example.com">
        <network 
            defaultCredentials="true" 
            host="localhost" 
            port="587" 
            userName="username" 
            password="password"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

**Read using MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0:**

```vb
<%

    Dim oXML, oNode
    
    Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    
        oXML.async = False    
        oXML.load Server.MapPath("/web.config")
        
        ' smtp attributes
        
        Set oNode = oXML.selectSingleNode("configuration/system.net/mailSettings/smtp")
                
            Response.Write "<b>deliveryMethod:</b> " & oNode.GetAttribute("deliveryMethod") & "<br>"
            Response.Write "<b>from:</b> " & oNode.GetAttribute("from") & "<br>"
        
        ' network attributes
                                            
        Set oNode = oXML.selectSingleNode("configuration/system.net/mailSettings/smtp/network")
                
            Response.Write "<b>defaultCredentials:</b> " & cBool(oNode.GetAttribute("defaultCredentials")) & "<br>"
            Response.Write "<b>host:</b> " & oNode.GetAttribute("host") & "<br>"
            Response.Write "<b>port:</b> " & cInt(oNode.GetAttribute("port")) & "<br>"
            Response.Write "<b>userName:</b> " & oNode.GetAttribute("userName") & "<br>"
            Response.Write "<b>password:</b> " & oNode.GetAttribute("password")
                                    
        Set oNode = Nothing
        
    Set oXML = Nothing
    
%>
```

**Output:**

> **deliveryMethod:** Network
>  **from:** smtp@example.com
>  **defaultCredentials:** True
>  **host:** localhost
>  **port:** 587
>  **userName:** username
>  **password:** password

Comment: thanks for the assistance @Adam